# PHP - How to modify multi-dimensional array item from within a function?

Tags: php, arrays

My problem is as follows. I have a multidimensional array. I declare my array. Then, I run some code that populates my array partially. Then i run a function, which among others is supposed to modify some item in my array from within the function. This is unfortunately not working. So my question is simple. Is it normal? And if yes, how can I overcome this. Thank you very much in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

```
$list = array([0]=>
                   array(
                         [name]=>'James' 
                         [group]=>''
                         )
             ); 



my_function();
print_r($list); 

function my_function(){
     //some code here
     $list[0]['group'] = 'groupA';
}
```

Comment: I take it your array is taken from `print_r`, and not actually `[0] =>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could pass the array to the function **by reference**

```
my_function(&$list) {

    $list[0]['group'] = 'groupA';
}

$list = /*...*/
my_function($list);
```

or simply **return** the array from the function

```
my_function($list) {

    $list[0]['group'] = 'groupA';
    return $list;
}

$list = /*...*/
$list = my_function($list);
```

or use a **global**

```
my_function() {

    global $list;
    $list[0]['group'] = 'groupA';
}

$list = /*...*/
my_function();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$list = array( 0 =>
                   array(
                         'name'=>'James' 
                         'group'=>''
                         )
             ); 



my_function($list);
print_r($list); 

function my_function(&$list){
     //some code here
     $list[0]['group'] = 'groupA';
}
```

alternatively:

```
$list = array(0 =>
                   array(
                         'name'=>'James' 
                         'group'=>''
                         )
             ); 



$list = my_function($list);
print_r($list); 

function my_function($list){
     //some code here
     $list[0]['group'] = 'groupA';
     return $list;
}
```

Comment: Hello Joe. Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately, I tried that but it is not working...

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the array is not changed, because it is in the global scope, and unlike other languages, PHP do not provide automatic access to the global scope from within function. So you have to do:

```
function my_function(){
     global $list;
     //some code here
     $list[0]['group'] = 'groupA';
}
```

But even better, pass the array as an argument by reference to the function

```
function my_function(&$list){
     //some code here
     $list[0]['group'] = 'groupA';
}
```

Comment: Helo Darhazer. Tks a lot. Both soution working great. Why is the second one better?

Comment: Because it will work even if you rename the variable in the global space, or in case you need to perform the same operation to different arrays. Generally, avoid using global variables (because you can accidently override a global variable), and coupling (with global you are working with the exactly one array, and passing it by reference enable you to work with any array)

Answer (score 0):

add ' in your internal array indexes

```
 array(
                         'name'=>'James' 
                         'group'=>''
      )
```